# How to return data from InfluxDB observer

Tags: javascript, influxdb

Consider the following exerpt from [this example](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/cloud/api-guide/client-libraries/nodejs/query/) in the InfluxDB documentation:

```
const fluxObserver = {
  next(row, tableMeta) {
    const o = tableMeta.toObject(row)
    console.log(
      `${o._time} ${o._measurement} in ${o.region} (${o.sensor_id}): ${o._field}=${o._value}`
    )
  },
  error(error) {
    console.error(error)
    console.log('\nFinished ERROR')
  },
  complete() {
    console.log('\nFinished SUCCESS')
  }
}

/** Execute a query and receive line table metadata and rows. */
queryApi.queryRows(fluxQuery, fluxObserver)
```

The `fluxObserver` defines a sequence of operations at different stages of execution of the query, all of which are just `console.log` calls. I can imagine that people want to do something similar in a way that is actually useful, like for instance `return` an array that contains the result of the query, instead of logging something to a console. My problem is that `queryApi.queryRows` does not actually return anything, so it is not possible to do something like:

```
...
  complete() {
    console.log('\nFinished SUCCESS')
    return data;
  }
}

/** Execute a query and receive line table metadata and rows. */
var result = queryApi.queryRows(fluxQuery, fluxObserver);
return result;
```

So how can I return the data collected by the `fluxObserver`?